# Weird effect on FF 42 with background repeat

Tags: html, css, firefox

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cf7w02Lo/):

You see a shaded line created by a stretched gif.

Below that is a div with a background with just this gif, stretched by repeat-x.

FF is causing to repeat the gif vertically at least 1 time, although no y repeat is set.

Works perfect on Chrome and Safari and has been working up to FF 41.0.2.

Can anyone explain if I'm doing things wrong or is this a browser bug?

html:

```
<img src="http://www.advertzoom.de/staging/imgs/csh_winstyle/dhxtoolbar_slider_middle.gif" width="300px" height="3px">
<br>&nbsp;
<div class="bgbox"></div>
```

css:

```
.bgbox {
    background-image: url("http://www.advertzoom.de/staging/imgs/csh_winstyle/dhxtoolbar_slider_middle.gif");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-size: 1px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width:300px;
}
```

**Edit**

Changing the height of the box from an even value to an odd value is toggling the effect. Seems likely to be a browser bug.

[image: FLattering background]

Comment: ff never uses literal css. it translates it into more optimized forms, which results in various unintended consequences. for instance, using !important in a sub property such as `padding-left:5px !important;` results in the parent property being completely overwritten, such as `padding: 0;`

Comment: Can you explain what you're seeing (maybe take a screenshot and post that on imgur)? I'm using FF 42 and don't see it repeated vertically. Maybe you have some addon that's messing things up?

Comment: No addons (except firebug). But if you slowly move the slider between CSS and Ouput section in jsfiddle, you might get aware of it

Comment: ditto, i'm not seeing it either

Comment: in your SS there isn't any changes to your `.bgbox` so what value did you change from odd to even?

Comment: It's also if you move arond the box (i.e. slowly move the slider between CSS and Result section in jsfiddle)

Comment: well using FF42 with win10, nothing changes

Comment: I'm currently using win7 64bit, FF 42 64bit and 32bit, same effect

Comment: Can't repro FF42 and 43.0b1 on osX

Comment: @r3wt Wait, what? Padding-left with !important overrides other padding values? I've never heard of that bug. Can you make a demo, or, show a bugzilla report?

Comment: Zoom is 100%. I have 1920*1200 usual screen resolution, nothing "abnormal".

Comment: @MrLister wow, you're right. Just compared Chrome and FF. Resetting FF settings to standard doesn't fix. Interesting, zoom shows 100% (although it isn't, obviously)

Comment: @MrLister Just installed Squint on FF and set the standard zoom to 80% which gives exactly the same sizes as Chrome on 100% and the effect is gone. I regard this to be a glitch in my FF installation at all. Questions is thus answered: Browser settings problem, not a programming issue. Post your comment as an answer and I upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is only visible when the zoom factor is not 100%. And apparently, the OP's browser was confused into thinking the zoom factor was 100% while it really was 125%. (As evident by the screenshots, where the 300px div is really 375 pixels wide.)

I remember that at one time Firefox could get confused by switching the "Zoom text only" menu item on or off while the zoom factor was not at 100%, but apparently that is not the case any more. Something else was going on.

So although the OP's real problem (why does FF think the zoom factor is something it isn't) is not really solved, the literal question is, the answer being "zoom factor". And it might not be specifically Firefox v42 related.